# Why isn't Snapshot isolation supported with Distributed Transactions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions, msdtc

Question is in the title.  I'd just love to understand why this isn't supported?

Just to clarify this is MS Sql Server 2005 / 2008.

Comment: I think the best answer I could give you is, "because it was not implemented"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's potentially inconsistent and it's weaker out of the box than lock-based isolation (ANSI SQL).

Or, the downsides ([such as this banking example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation#Making_Snapshot_Isolation_Serializable)) require more work and thinking to keep things correct so it's simply safer not to support it.

Finally (I've not checked), is it in the ANSI standard? It could be a very bespoke solution and you'd be unable to use distributed transactions against other platforms

[Link 1](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1538909.1538913)

Comment: No the technical implementation of the locking seems fine, as to how it works.  I just don't understand why they haven't allowed snapshot to work when MSDTC performs the commit.  It works with all other levels, just not snapshot :'(

Comment: Link 2 is broken (to me). Could you please provide the name of the cited paper?